# Speed of a program using 'require'

Tags: ruby, require

```
class Example
  attr_accessor :test
end

a = Example.new
```

If I have a class I want to use, like `Example`, is this way of holding everything in one file, faster than using 'require' to get this class from a different file? If so, how significant a difference are we talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It isn't faster. Honestly, it doesn't make a difference at all.

The advantage you get putting it in a separate file is that:

1. Other files can use it using the `require` call
2. It's easier to keep track of things and maintain if you need to.

Comment: Yes, it is faster, but nearly imperceptibly so. And the nearly-irrelevant speed “boost” is not worth what you lose in readability and maintainability.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall - It needs to be pointed out why it is faster. It's only faster when LOADING the program, since loading everything from one file is faster than loading from multiple files. As far as running times they are identical. Of course you know that, but Kuba probably did not.

Comment: File I/O will add some delay time as the individual files are opened and read. That process of finding and opening a file, then reading it, adds up the more files you read, but it's not a big deal; Compared to the execution time of an app, the load time is usually pretty minor.